# Problem running webdriver inside python function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to do some tests. I created function to do what i need to repeat. The problem is that when i run the get element inside function i got nothing and when i run it directly everything work.
Here is my code:

```
import selenium as se
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta 
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='selenuim/Chromedriver')
browser.get('XXX')
```

```
def download(browser):
    print(browser);
    download =browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), 
      "Télécharger au format CSV")]')[0];
    download.click()
    print('modal='+ 
      str(browser.find_elements_by_class_name('modal_content')));
    modal = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('modal_content')[0]
    form = modal.find_elements_by_class_name("form-group")[0]
    print('form='+form);
    time.sleep(1)
    DestInfo = form.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[contains(text(), 
      "Afficher les informations sur le destinataire")]')[0];
    DestInfo.click()
    CustomField = form.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[contains(text(), 
       "Afficher les champs personnalisés")]')[0];
    CustomField.click()
```

when i run

```
download(browser)
```

I get nothing, the list is empty

```
<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="ca2d70cc17b9205c66d9509d55672142")>
modal=[]
```

and when i run directly, i got 1 element

```
browser.find_elements_by_class_name('modal_content')
```

i get

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ca2d70cc17b9205c66d9509d55672142", element="185869a1-dc9a-4f8f-bc4d-22214b55974e")>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you need to wait **modal-content** web element appears. try to add *sleep* or use selenium waiter

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

timeout = 5
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout, poll_frequency=1)
wait.until(
  method=ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='modal_content']")))  # put your selector
```